# Apply shipping costs calculation before checkout

Tags: expresso-store

I've set up shipping methods in Store which have rules of "Country" and "Region" set to "(any)" but when I'm displaying my cart, the shipping costs are not included until the shipping address is set.

As I want to have shipping costs that don't rely on location, would it be possible to make Store apply the shipping costs matching this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shipping costs will still be calculated even before your cart has a shipping address (assuming some rules match). Are you sure this isn't just a problem with your template? (e.g. displaying `{order_subtotal}` instead of `{order_total}`?

Normally even if your shipping costs do depend on a region, you would set a default country and region under Store > Settings > Countries & Regions. This means shipping costs can be calculated before the customer adds their address.

Comment: Actually, when I'm logged out, the shipping row doesn't display and `{order_shipping}` returns 0 until I connect to an account which has billing and shipping already known and there it works.

I have this code for the row : `{if shipping_method_id}{order_shipping}{/if}` wrapped in a checkout tag.

Thanks !

Comment: I've tested resetting my cookies, added items to cart, and the cart nor checkout tag don't display shipping costs until I click on the Update button. So no need of a shipping address, but don't understand why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Have you set a default shipping method for new carts in the CP, or are you simply setting it on the checkout template? That would explain why it doesn't work til the first time you update totals.

Comment: Great ! I hadn't noticed this "Pre-selected shipping method" setting, my bad... Problem solved, thanks for you help !

Comment: No problem! Glad that fixed it.